# Is there any way to remove the "Code Snippet" from a string?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have figure tags in a string

```
const content = 'Here is a sentence followed up with <figure><img /></figure> plus some more text.'
```

Is there a way I can check to see if there is a figure tag in the string, select the tags and all of its contents, and remove or filter out all of them with React or Javascript?

The desired output would be

```
const content = 'Here is a sentence followed up with plus some more text.'
```

I know it is not clean but it supports an Algolia query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx for this. One possible RegEx would be `/(<figure>.+<\/figure>)/g` (https://regexr.com/6ke0o)

So some sample code would look like this:

```js
const content = 'Here is a sentence followed up with <figure><img /></figure> plus some more text.'.replace(/(<figure>.+<\/figure>)/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to remove tags (NOT tag body):

```js
console.log("Here is a sentence followed up with <figure><img /><\figure> plus some more text.".replaceAll(/<\\?[a-zA-Z\s]+\/?>/g,""))
```

or:

```
.replaceAll( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
```

if you want to just remove `figure` tag:

```js
console.log("Here is a sentence followed up with <figure><img/><\figure> plus some more text.".replaceAll(/<figure>.+<\figure>/g,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DOM parser, create an element, put your content in as innerHTML, and filter the childNodes so that only text nodes remain.

```js
const content = 'Here is a sentence followed up with <figure><img /></figure> plus some more text.'

const tester = document.createElement('div');
tester.innerHTML = content;

const output = [...tester.childNodes].filter(child => child.nodeType === 3).map(child => child.nodeValue.trim()).join(" ");

console.log(output);
```